# Convert milliSeconds To Gregorian Calendar

Tags: android, time, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I want to convert milliSeconds in long format to Gregorian Calendar.
By searching in the web, i use the code below:

```
public static String getStringDate(int julianDate){
    GregorianCalendar gCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    Time gTime = new Time();
    gTime.setJulianDay(julianDate);
    gCal.setTimeInMillis(gTime.toMillis(false));
    String gString = Utils.getdf().format(gCal.getTime());
    return gString;
}

public static SimpleDateFormat getdf(){
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:MM",Locale.US);
}
```

Yes, the code works but i find that only the date and the hour are correct but there are errors on minutes. Say if the thing happens on 2014-11-06, 14:00, it will give me 2014-11-06, 14:11. I want to know are there any solutions to modify it or it is not recommended to convert time into Gregorian Calendar. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually is very simple, 
modify SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:MM",Locale.US) with

SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm",Locale.getDefault());

will solve the problem

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( millis )                  // Convert count-from-epoch into a `Instant` object for a moment in UTC.
    .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )  // Adjust from UTC to a particular time zone. Same moment, different wall-clock time. Renders a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .format(                                    // Generate a String in a particular format to represent the value of our `ZonedDateTime` object.
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd, HH:mm" )
    )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes instead of those troublesome legacy classes.

Convert your count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 (1970-01-01T00:00Z) to a `Instant` object. Be aware that `Instant` is capable of finer granularity of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millis ) ;
```

That moment is in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). To adjust into another time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generate a string in your desired format using a `DateTimeFormatter` object.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd, HH:mm" , Locale.US ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).